# Fetch whether Windows Firewall group contains all the enable rules or not

Tags: powershell, firewall, powershell-4.0, windows-firewall

I wanted to fetch the boolean value whether the Windows Firewall group contains all the enabled rule or disabled rule. I am trying fetching the details through this command

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "XYZ" -Enabled "True"
```

But this is returning me the details of every rule which is enabled in the group XYZ.

I wanted to perform something like this

If the firewall group contains 10 rules and those 10 rules are enabled then the module return true else return false.

```
if("All the rules in a group is enabled"){*Do some stuff*} else{"Do some different stuff"}
```

How can I do that? Any different PowerShell module will also work.

Comment: what version of PoSh are you working with? i don't think that cmdlet is available with ps3 ...

Comment: I am using 4.0, any other way to perform that task?

Comment: Maybe you could build a solution based on [netsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh) ?

Comment: PLEASE, remove the incorrect version info.

Comment: for the actual problem, you can save the result of your call to a $Var, and then compare the count of all results with the count of results that have `.Enabled` set to `$True`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Actually, .Enabled isn't boolean, it's a different "Enabled" enum type.

Comment: @js2010 - thank you for that info! [*grin*] i don't have access to that cmdlet, so was not able to test it. [*sigh ...*]

Answer (score 0):

If you simply reverse your logic checking if any enabled property is false, you can achieve your desired result.

```
# If any one is false it will do other stuff
if(Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Network Discovery" -Enabled "false")
{
    "Do other stuff"
}
else
{
    "Do stuff"
}
```

You could also check if false exists in the array of enabled properties like this

```
# If all are True, it will do stuff
if('false' -notin (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Network Discovery").enabled)
{
    "Do stuff"
}
else
{
    "Do other stuff"
}
```